# Coefficients in Faulhabers' sum $\sum n^{2m+1}, \ m=0,1,2...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Review a preprint named [*Johann Faulhaber and Sums of Powers*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9207222) by Donald E. Knuth, on page 10 are shown sums of $n$ to odd powers, for example,
$$\sum n^1=\binom{n+1}{2},$$
$$\sum n^3=6\binom{n+2}{4}+\binom{n+1}{2},$$
$$\sum n^5=120\binom{n+3}{6}+30\binom{n+2}{4}+\binom{n+1}{2},$$

and so on...

**Question 1**. How can we produce coefficients $\{1,6,1,120,30,1\}$ in this expressions by generating function, and what function is it?

PS they are closely related to central factorial numbers https://oeis.org/A008957 but exact formula is states unclear.

Comment: What is unclear about A008957 formula? I added info to the sequence entry yesterday.

Comment: Reviewing the Knuth's preprint (end of the page 10) we can find that $$\Sigma n^{2m+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{m} (2k-1)!T(2m,2k)\binom{n+k}{2k},$$ for sure one can think that our coefficients are produced by $$\sum_{k=1}^{m} (2k-1)!T(2m,2k),$$ where $T(2m,2k)$ is central factorial numbers (https://oeis.org/A008957). But it's not true, hereby the question is still opened

Comment: What do you mean "it's not true"?. Did you look at my added info in A005957 yet? It has e.g.f.

Comment: I cant see how A005957 is connected to our question

Comment: We have a sequence which connected to https://oeis.org/A008957 but we still dont have exact function with produces the term of Knuth's coefficients, that is the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Question 1 is answered in [OES sequence A008957](http://oeis.org/A008957). For example, the coefficients $\;(1,6,1,120,30,1,\dots)\;$ are expressed in terms of A008957 exactly how Knuth meant it: 
$$\;(1!\cdot1,\;\;3!\cdot1,1!\cdot1,\;\;5!\cdot1,3!\cdot5,1!\cdot1,\;\;7!\cdot1,5!\cdot14,3!\cdot21,1!\cdot1,\;\;\dots).\;$$
The triangular sequence A008957 has as exponential generating function
$$ x^2\! \cosh(\sinh(y\; x/2)/(x/2))\!-\!1)= (1x^2)y^2/2!\! +\!(1x^2\!+\!1x^4)y^4/4!\! +\!(1x^2\!+\!5x^4\!+\!1x^6)y^6/6!+\cdots.$$

Comment: Oh yes, finally i understood it, thank you

Comment: Thanks for pushing me to add info to OEIS and to explain it here.

Comment: Please take a particiaption in addition of this sequence to OEIS, it is now proceeding under https://oeis.org/draft/A303675

Comment: I think you and the the editors of OEIS can handle the job based on what is already known. I will observe the process.